# Выбрать самое частое значение в строке датафрема

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм.

```
    column1 column2 column3
0   high    medium  low
1   medium  medium  high
2   low     medium  low
```

нужно в каждой строке найти повторяющиеся значение и записать его в колонку4, если повторяющихся значений нет, то выбрать рандомно. Т.е в первой строке значение выбирается рандомно и сохраняется в колонку4, во второй строке в колонку4 сохраняется medium, в третьей строке колонка4=low.

при выполнении этого кода

```
df['column4'] = df.apply(lambda row: max(row, key=row.count), axis=1)
```

получаю ошибку: ValueError: Series.count level is only valid with a MultiIndex

Comment: `df.mode(axis=1)[0]`

Comment: @splash58 не совсем случайный результат, ка кпри отсутствии моды, так и при наличии более одного одинаково часто встречающегося значения )

Comment: @strawdog а что  такое случайный, чем наименьший плох? я случайно выбираю все первые. можно взять случайные не nan

Comment: @strawdog сделал случайный :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.mode(axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().sample(1).values[0], axis=1)

0    high
1  medium
2     low
```

> pandas.mode
>
> The mode of a set of values is the value that appears most often. It
> can be multiple values.
>
> Для набора значений возвращает наиболее часто встречающийся элемент

> pandas.sample
>
> Return a random sample of items from an axis of object.
>
> Возвращает случайный элемент

Про dropna, думаю, можно не писать

Comment: круто, но в случае с sample он далеко не всегда выдаст один столбец ;). скорее даже наоборот - чаще выдаст два, с нанами в перемешку

Comment: надо, наверное, как-то так: `df.mode(axis=1).apply(lambda x:  pd.Series(x.dropna().sample(1).to_numpy()), axis=1)`

Comment: @strawdog sample вернет один по определению функции. зачем преобразовывать туда-сюда воо втором комментарии, я не понял. в моем ответе мы получаем уже построчный результат. Зачем же каждую строку превращать в Series?

Comment: а вы свой код прогоните несколько раз на исходном датафрейме.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо. прозевал. ща поправлю